# Read text file then list year and rank from data set

Tags: java

This is my text file that I want to read data from:

```
|RANK|  1950| 1994| 1998|
|   1|   JIN|  KIM| JOHN|
|   2|   JIM|  KIM|  RON|
|   3|  FRED|CRAIG|  JIN|
|   4|  JOHN| MARK|  DON|
```

I would like to open up the data file and prompt the user to input the name above, then program can list the year and rank for the name from the data set.

This is what I've done so far using Netbeans:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class JavaTask1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //file instance
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("mynames.txt");

   try{

        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        //create scanner object
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter name:> ");

    String myname = in.nextLine(); //read user input



    String[] fullData;
    while(input.hasNext()){        

    //split data 
    fullData = input.next().split("\\|");

    ArrayList<String> yearList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> rankList = new ArrayList<>();
    //populate both arraylist from file        

   ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> matrix = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
   //Populate the matrix of names from file into matrix;


   for(int x=0; x<matrix.size(); x++)
for(int y=0; y<matrix.get(x).size(); y++){
    String currName = matrix.get(x).get(y);
    if(currName.equalsIgnoreCase(myname))
        System.out.println("Year (" + yearList.get(y) + ") Ranked " + rankList.get(x));
}               
    }

    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("Error the file cannot be found");
    }
}
```

}

I would like the program to output as follows:

```
Enter name: > John

Year (1998) Ranked 1

Year (1950) Ranked 4
```

I'm confused on whether to use nested loops to loop through each data or arraylist to store each data then output it using if statement. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm confused on whether to use nested loops to loop through each data or arraylist to store each data then output it using if statement. Please help.

You can treat this problem like asking you to find the X and Y coordinates by searcing for a specific value through a 2D array.

You can use ArrayList of ArrayList to store your matrix (data) if the number of rows and columns are arbitrary. But since your "coordinates" are "Rank" and "Year" instead of running numbers, you need to store the values of ranks and years as well (for ease of retrieval):

```
ArrayList<String> yearList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> rankList = new ArrayList<>();
//populate both arraylist from file
```

Then use ArrayList of ArrayList (also possible to use array of array) to store the matrix of data:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> matrix = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
//Populate the matrix of names from file into matrix;
```

Followed by using nested for-loop to iterate through the matrix:

```
for(int x=0; x<matrix.size(); x++)
    for(int y=0; y<matrix.get(x).size(); y++){
        String currName = matrix.get(x).get(y);
        if(currName.equalsIgnoreCase(name))
            System.out.println("Year (" + yearList.get(y) + ") Ranked " + rankList.get(x));
    }
```

**However** if you are using ArrayList, you can make use of `indexOf()` to get the index by searching the name which allows you to use **one** for-loop:

```
for(int x=0; x<matrix.size(); x++){
    int yearIdx = matrix.get(x).indexOf(name);
    if(yearIdx >= 0)
        System.out.println("Year (" + yearList.get(yearIdx) + ") Ranked " + rankList.get(x));
}
```

Comment: Hi, I got an error with cannot find symbol with the nested for loop to iterate through the matrix. Do i need to create a get method for get(y)

Comment: @Vinay I have edited my solution. You don't need rows and cols. 1 Arraylist is enough.

Comment: Hello, I tried it with the code. Still not working I used scanner input and while loop as edited is there something wrong, please.